# Does cassandra 0.7 work with Thrift 0.7

Tags: cassandra, thrift

May I know if any body has successfully tried this combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Cassandra 0.7 uses Thrift 0.5, which is not wire compatible with Thrift 0.6+.

Cassandra 1.0 was recently released; 0.7 is pretty old at this point.  I suggest upgrading.

Comment: A Thrift 0.6+ client is definitely wire-compatible with an 0.5 server (and vice-versa).  Perhaps you're thinking of supported features in the interface definition (like enums, for example)?